# How can one pause/resume a dynamically loaded external SWF file using ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip, playback

I'd like to be able to play/pause dynamically loaded external SWF movies using ActionScript 3.0.  Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loaded SWF's are accessible through the Loader's **content** property. 
You can cast the content property to your loaded SWF's Document Class to access methods of your SWF directly. Of course you can simply use the play(); and stop(); ... if you just want to play time-line animations :

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader("anim.swf");
addChild(loader);

loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

function completeHandler(e:Event):void
{
    var movie:MovieClip = e.target.content;
    movie.play();
}
```